# Присвоение переменной js к id блоку

Tags: html, javascript

Добрый день! Подскажите, как можно присвоить id номер блоку div из javascript. С учетом того, что id для дива должно задаваться из яваскрипта, а не наоборот.

Вот делаю, к примеру, так:

```
<script>var idf = 5;</script>

...

<div id="(idf)"> ... </div>
```

Как-то так сделать, чтобы диву присвоить номер из скрипта. Спросите, почему такое извращение? Так потому что делаю на шаблонизаторе загрузку блоков, где, соответственно, php не работает, только яваскрипт и чистый html. Такое вообще возможно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    var idf = 5;
    document.write('<div id="' + idf + '"> ... </div>');
</script>
```